# How to view available webapi methods?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I know this has got to be a super easy question I should just be able to google, but for the life of me I can't figure out what keywords to search for so as not to bring up a bunch of noise that has nothing to do with my question.

I have a WebApi project and it is running, as evidenced by the fact I can make calls to it successfully from another application. However I am trying to add a new method to call and I keep getting a 404 when I try to call it.

The other day I *thought* that I was able to view a web page that listed available service calls simply by going to the root url of the services from a browser. However I am getting a 404 when I do that now also.

So my question is, where am I supposed to go that will cause the wepapi application to show me what service calls are available? I'd like to see if my new method is even showing up there.

Comment: Have you checked out swagger?

Comment: Nope, I'll take a look. Still trying to figure out how the heck I was able to view a list of methods automatically the other day though.

Comment: No idea, but swagger is very nice. Not only does it allow you to view your endpoints as web page, but on that page you can fill out text boxes and make the web requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Just add `/help` as in `http://hostname/help`.